# Node.js how do you send a HttpOnly cookie after a post request (login)?

Tags: node.js, authentication, cookies, routes, httpcookie

**Goal/Problem**

I am trying to figure out how to send a HttpOnly cookie after a post(login) request. I think I understand how to create one. The problem is that I can't create one within my post(login) route.

**What I've tried**

I tried creating a HttpOnly cookie on my post and it failed. Then I realized that doing a get route would create my HttpOnly cookie. I also tried doing doing a next() to my get route but I could not get it working. I also tried changing my post(login) into a get but I ran into the issue that my data passed on req.body is "undefined".

**Cookie Route** (using "cookie", and "express" package)

```
  router.get('/setcookie', (req, res)=>{ 
    res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookie.serialize('name', "secretcookie", {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
    }));
    next();
  });
```

**Login Route**

```
router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;

    var sql = "SELECT * FROM user_tables where user_tables.Name = '" + username + "' AND user_tables.Password='" + password + "'";
    connectsql.query(sql, function (err, rows, fields) {
            if (rows.length === 1) {
                console.log(sql);
                console.log(rows[0].ID);
                const token = jwt.sign({P_id: rows[0].ID, P_username: username}, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET, {expiresIn: "2m"});
            } 
            else {
                console.log(sql);
                console.log("authentication failed"); //send  response of 401 for auth failed
            }
        })
})
```

I would appreciate the help very very much! If there is a better approach for this please let me know.

Comment: Unrelated, but I think your code is vulnerable to SQL injection (You don't escape username or password) unless `.query()` allows such usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handler in your `login` route is not returning anything. You have to set the header with the cookie in the `res` object and either call `res.end()` or `next()`.
Assuming that your are using `express` it should be like this.

```js
const express = require('express')
const cookie = require('cookie')

const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  return res.send(`<form method="POST" action="/login"><button type=submit>LOGIN!!</button></form>`)
})

app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookie.serialize('foo', 'bar', { httpOnly: true }))
  return res.send(`<body><h1>SUCCESS!!</h1></body>`);
})

app.listen(8000, () => console.log('listening'))
```

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Stackoverflow! :D Thank you for the comment. I am aware I'm not returning anything. Doing the following code gives me an `Error: Request failed with status code 404` I can't execute the res.Header line you provided. I already tried this. It seems like it should work but in my case it isn't. My goal is to get a HttpOnly cookie within login route or calling a get route to set a HttpOnly cookie. As far as I know using a get route gives me HttpOnly cookie without an error.

Comment: Are you using express?

Comment: ah I tested it out again. I'm really sorry! Yeah it did execute properly. I tested it with a REST client and it does display similarly to your request on curl but when I actually do it on the browser I do not see any cookie created.

Comment: I updated my answer with a more browser functional example. I tested on both Firefox and Chrome and the cookie is being set correctly.

Comment: Thank you!! and thank you for being patient with me. I tested it out and it works successfully! One thing that confuses me is that why can't I just immediately go to my `/login` route to set the cookie? Is there a way that I can set a cookie without doing a submit form?

Comment: The route is expecting a POST, when you go to the route in your browser that's always a GET. Change the handler from post to get in the server and it should work. Usually a login action would be a POST call.

Comment: That makes sense. Would it be safe/ok to do a res.redirect() to a `GET`? where I get the cookie there or would you suggest something else?

Comment: actually a redicrect won't let me access my token though. If I change my post to a `GET` then my req.body will be undefined.

Comment: I actually figured it out now I can always just pass the token using `res.redirect("/auth?token=" + token);` then calling it with `req.query.token` Thank You! I think you went above and beyond on the help! Thanks!